# Date Time null model schema display swashbuckle + swagger ui

Tags: c#, datetime, null, swashbuckle

I have implemented Swashbuckle and Swagger UI to do my API documentation.

I'm having a problem with correctly displaying a nullable `DateTime`, or any nullable object for that matter.

Currently a nullable `DateTime` displays as `"date": "2016-05-27T00:15:41.658Z"`in the response model schema.

The response model displays the date as `date (string, optional)` which states that it's optional, but it also displays that for a non-nullable `DateTime`.

I've tried to add default value via: [Default model example in Swashbuckle (Swagger)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28911023/default-model-example-in-swashbuckle-swagger) and also tried to add a model schema example via the last answer.

Any ideas on how I can get `"date": "null"` to display in the model schema? Or alternatively find a better way to give the person reading the documentation an indication that the `date` object can be null?

Answer (score 1):

**The short answer**

You can't and you shouldn't

**The slightly longer answer**

Basically the documentation provided, `date (string, optional)`, is already telling your consumers that the property can be null or missing in a request or a response. So, providing an example with `"date": null` isn't very helpful. Providing an example with a valid date, however, is helpful: it gives the consumer an idea of what the date looks like.

Now, on to the `DateTime` and `DateTime?` properties server side. When the server receives an object with a missing date, the type of the property determines the value. When a property with type `DateTime` is missing, ASP.Net Web API will set that property to the minimal date (01-01-0001Z00:00:00). However, when a property with type `DateTime?` is missing, ASP.Net Web API will set that property to null.

The same goes for the response sent by the server. When the server sends an object with a property of type `DateTime` it will always send a value. However, when a property with type `DateTime?`is send, the sent property will only have a value when `HasValue' of the property is true. Otherwise the response won't have the property.

Comment: Thanks, agreed that `"date": null` isn't very helpful. The confusion comes in when `DateTime` objects in the API also show as `date (string, optional)`. Doesn't seem right to me as this isn't optional.

So what you're saying is that they have to null check every property? That's an enormous amount of overhead...

Comment: If you want to express that a date property always has a value, you can use the `[Required]` attribute. In that case the property will be documented as `date (string)`.

Comment: Thanks @venerik. That's fine for outgoing DTO's but incoming objects we apply our own validation to all properties so we can't add `[Required]`.