# Edit schema in IOperationFilter

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, swashbuckle

I am using Swashbuckle for **APIDocumentation**. I have made custom attribute by following [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28911023/default-model-example-in-swashbuckle-swagger) **(DefaultValue attribute)** and one attribute **(swaggerIgnore)** by my self. The **DefaultValue** is working fine but other custom attribute finds the node and give me the property on which I set but schema I edit in it and the property I manually remove any property in it could not update and show me all the porperties in UI.

Here is my sample code.

```
public class SwaggerIgnore : Attribute
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
 public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
    {
        if (operation.parameters == null)
            return;
        IDictionary<string, object> parameterValuePairs = GetParameterValuePairs(apiDescription.ActionDescriptor);
        var retVal = GetParameters(apiDescription.ActionDescriptor);

        foreach (var param in operation.parameters)
        {
            if (param.schema != null && param.schema.@ref != null)
            {
                string schemaName = param.schema.@ref.Split('/').LastOrDefault();
                if (schemaRegistry.Definitions.ContainsKey(schemaName))
                    foreach (var props in schemaRegistry.Definitions[schemaName].properties)
                    {
                        if (parameterValuePairs.ContainsKey(props.Key))
                            props.Value.@default = parameterValuePairs[props.Key];
                    }
```

> Removing Code Starts Here...

```
foreach (var item in schemaRegistry.Definitions[schemaName].properties)
            {
            if (retVal != null && item.Key == retVal)
         {
         schemaRegistry.Definitions[schemaName].properties.Remove(item);
                    break;
                }
            }
```

> Removing Code Ends Here..

```
           }

            var parameterValuePair = parameterValuePairs.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key.IndexOf(param.name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);
            param.@default = parameterValuePair.Value;
        }
    }

    private IDictionary<string, object> GetParameterValuePairs(HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> parameterValuePairs = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        foreach (SwaggerDefaultValue defaultValue in actionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<SwaggerDefaultValue>())
        {
            parameterValuePairs.Add(defaultValue.Name, defaultValue.Value);
        }

        foreach (var parameter in actionDescriptor.GetParameters())
        {
            if (!parameter.ParameterType.IsPrimitive)
            {
                foreach (PropertyInfo property in parameter.ParameterType.GetProperties())
                {
                    var defaultValue = GetDefaultValue(property);

                    if (defaultValue != null)
                    {
                        parameterValuePairs.Add(property.Name, defaultValue);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return parameterValuePairs;
    }

    private static object GetDefaultValue(PropertyInfo property)
    {
        var customAttribute = property.GetCustomAttributes<SwaggerDefaultValue>().FirstOrDefault();

        if (customAttribute != null)
        {
            return customAttribute.Value;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

**Usage of Custom attribute.**

```
[SwaggerDefaultValue("uzair")]
    public String StudentName { set; get; }
[SwaggerIgnore]
    public String FatherName { set; get; }
```