# Setting up examples in Swagger

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I am using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger (1.0.0) and Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen (1.0.0). I am trying to add default examples to my API following [Default model example in Swashbuckle (Swagger)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28911023/default-model-example-in-swashbuckle-swagger). I created a new class file and added,

```
public class SwaggerDefaultValue : Attribute
{
    public string ParameterName { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public SwaggerDefaultValue(string parameterName, string value)
    {
        this.ParameterName = parameterName;
        this.Value = value;
    }
}

public class AddDefaultValues : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, DataTypeRegistry dataTypeRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
    {
        foreach (var param in operation.Parameters)
        {
            var actionParam = apiDescription.ActionDescriptor.GetParameters().First(p => p.ParameterName == param.Name);

            if (actionParam != null)
            {
                var customAttribute = actionParam.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<SwaggerDefaultValue>().FirstOrDefault();
                if (customAttribute != null)
                {
                    param.DefaultValue = customAttribute.Value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but I get this error - `AddDefaultValues does not implement interface member IOperationFilter.Apply(Operation, OperationFilterContext)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That link you are following is not for the [Swashbuckle.AspNetCore](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore) version

Look in the correct project for the proper examples:
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/search?q=IOperationFilter&unscoped_q=IOperationFilter