# Generating Get requests examples with swashbuckle for Swagger UI

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I've seen some resources for generating a request example & defaults with Swashbuckle:

[Default model example in Swashbuckle (Swagger)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28911023/default-model-example-in-swashbuckle-swagger)

The defaults works fine for a get Operation with a query string parameters. But is there any way to generate a request example for a Get operation? or is it only available for non get operations?

Comment: I've been looking for answer for the same purpose.